# Preferences getting locked

Tags: java, preferences

The reason is that the preferences-systems tries to write a lock file at a location where "normal" users have no write permissions on Linux workstations. (/opt/j2se/linux/ix86/j2se_1.5.0_12/jre/.systemPrefs/.system.lock)

1)I cant give write permission to the directory.

2)I   am doing something like this:

```
private void loadSamplePreferences() throws IOException,
            BackingStoreException, InvalidPreferencesFormatException {
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader();
        InputStream stream = contextClassLoader
                .getResourceAsStream("example.xml");

        Preferences pref = Preferences.systemRoot().node("example");

        pref.removeNode();


        Preferences.importPreferences(stream);
    }
```

I tried to setpreferences with dummy factory  but still problem exists in loading

```
 System.setProperty("java.util.prefs.PreferencesFactory", "DisabledPreferencesFactory");
       System.setProperty("java.util.prefs.systemRoot", targetpath);
       System.setProperty("java.util.prefs.userRoot", targetpath);
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use `Preferences pref = Preferences.userRoot().node("example");` ... systemRoot is intended for system wide preferences for all users.

Comment: For a situation where different users have their own preferences on a shared computer, I think this is the better way to go.

Comment: This is correct. The real reason for the error is that constantlearner was asking for the system preferences, which requires an administrator (root on linux). But you can redirect the location of system preferences, and user preferences, to a different location with system properties on the JVM. You change the location to a writeable directory. However, having system properties in a location that is writeable by all is probably not a great idea.